# Reference methods from another class in traceur

Tags: ecmascript-6, traceur

I'm testing classes in ES6 using traceur but it's not working as I expected.

I am trying to use a method as a reference in another class but when it's called I get the reference of the caller class when read the value of `this`.

Here is my code:

```
class A {
    constructor(anotherMethod){
        this.anotherMethod = anotherMethod;
        this.name = "A";
    }
    myMethod (){
        console.log(this.name);
        this.anotherMethod();
    }
}

class B {
    constructor(){
        this.a = new A(this.myMethod);
        this.name = "B";
    }
    myMethod(){
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

var c = new B();
c.a.myMethod();
```

My expected log is:

```
A
B
```

But it is showing:

```
A
A
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: *"but when it's called I get the reference of the caller class when read the value of `this`"* That's simply how `this` works in JavaScript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: @FelixKling I understand that. But it is confusing because you don't have an universal variable to access the current class instance. You can't rely on 'this' variable if you are not sure on how your methods will be used by others.

Comment: That's true. However, if the methods are not called as intended, then they probably won't work, in which case someone will likely change the code to make it work (and call them as intended). You shouldn't have to consider the mistakes others might make. What you should do is provide a clear API and documentation. If someone doesn't use library correctly, it's their problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class B, when the constructor function runs:

```
this.a = new A(this.myMethod);
```

You're actually setting the method `myMethod` of B to A. When A's constructor runs,

this.myMethod, is set to A's anotherMethod. Now if you try printing `this.a` in your B's constructor you will get `name : A`. Which is actually referencing the class A.

Now when you try executing the method, `c.a.myMethod()`, As A contains the reference to `class A`, it's invoking the `myMethod` of A. Inside this method, `this` will refer to the current execution context object which is A. That's the reason why you're seeing `A` in both the consoles.

In short, You're only assigning the function to A and not setting the context.

You can force `fat arrow` using below:

```
class B {
    constructor(){
        this.a = new A(this.myMethod);
        this.name = "B";
    }

     myMethod = () => {
            console.log(this);
     }
}
```

Now you will get the desired output. But unfortunately `traceur` doesn't support it. Only babel supports `fat arrow` inside functions which is part of `ES7 stage 0 Class Properties`.

As suggested by Felix King: Binding the context using `bind` is more than enough currently

```
class B {
    constructor(){
        this.a = new A(this.myMethod.bind(this));
        this.name = "B";
    }

     myMethod() {
            console.log(this);
     }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but it's not the expected behavior of classes, right? If you write similar code in another languages it will work. In coffeescript it work if you use the fat arrow, but traceur do not support fat arrow in methods, or does it?

Comment: It raises "Unexpected token".

Comment: Yes traceur doesn't support fat arrow inside methods

Comment: The explanation is correct, but arrow functions don't solve that problem. Arrow functions resolve `this` in the *lexical* scope. So in this example `this` resolves to the global object or the module's `this` (which is `undefined`).

Comment: Ah I see now. The actual feature you are using is **class properties** (`class A { foo = bar }`). This is an ES7 stage 0 proposal: http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/, https://gist.github.com/jeffmo/054df782c05639da2adb . I wouldn't really recommend using it at this point. Simply calling `new A(this.myMethod.bind(this));` would work just as well.